# Preventing empty space after swipe in iOS

Tags: jquery, html, ios, css

I am trying to prevent empty space after swiping on iOS. Of course, these empty spaces are temporary, but they ruin some elements positions. You can check [the website.](http://csstr.com/soc/)

I checked it on my old iPad. I don't know if empty spaces occur on iPhone as well. There isn't any unwanted space on Android.

Pics:
[image]
[image]

**Relevant CSS for Body and Wrapper:**

```
html, body {
height: 100%; 
overflow: hidden;
}

#wrapper{
height: 100%;
position: relative;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
touch-action:none;
z-index: 9;
transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
color: #ffffff;
background: #222222;
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
```

**UPDATE1** I found an example about this problem. Alvaro's [fullpage plugin](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) prevents to occur these unwanted spaces. I didn't figure it out how he dealt with this problem.

Comment: I found a temporary solution for this webpage. I disabled touchmove with JQuery, because main page is full size (width:100%, height:100%). But touchmove isnot disabled for content pages (.section). So I can use scroll. At least, when the website is loaded, unwanted spaces don't occur. As I said, it's just temporary solution and works for websites like my page. Touchmove jquery codes;  $(document).on("touchmove", function(e) { e.preventDefault() }); $(document).on("touchmove", ".section", function(e) { e.stopPropagation() }); I still open for the certain solutions.

Comment: Hi again guys, I finally solved this problem by using jquery plugin iscroll 5. There isn't unwanted space or page bouncing anymore on ios. I just wanted to let you know.